# Spring + multiple H2 instances in memory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, h2

Two different H2 instances to be created in-memory. To make sure this happens, I initialized both instances with same shema and different data. So that when I query using DAO different set of data picked from different DataSource. However this is not happening. What am I doing wrong? How to name the instance of H2 correct?

```
@Bean(name = "DS1")
@Primary
public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource1() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
            setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).
            setName("DB1").
            addScript("schema.sql").
            addScript("data-1.sql").
            build();

}

@Bean(name = "DS2")
public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource2() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().
            setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).
            setName("DB2").
            addScript("schema.sql").
            addScript("data-2.sql").
            build();

}
```

Comment: Is your `schema.sql` creating databases with the same name?

Comment: You can't declare two primary beans of a same type - probably this is the cause of unexpected behavior

Comment: This was a typo in copy paste. Actually only the first DS is @Primary. Still it does not work.

Comment: @willOEM - Yes schema.sql creates same tables. But data is different. In this way I can test if my code really picks up data from 2 different Database or not.

Comment: Can you connect to your H2 instance and see both databases?  My guess is there is only one that is being overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

You have created two DataSources and have marked one as @Primary -- this is the one which will be used when your EntityManagerFactories and Repositories are autoconfigured.  That's why both DAO's are accessing the same database.

In order to get around this, you need to declare two separate EntityManagerFactories, as described in the Spring Boot documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-two-entity-managers

After that, you'll need to declare two separate repositories and tell each repository which of the EntityManagerFactory to use. To do this, in your @EnableJpaRepositories annotation you'll have to specify the correct EntityMangerFactory.  This article describes very nicely how to do that:

http://scattercode.co.uk/2013/11/18/spring-data-multiple-databases/

It would be nice if Spring Boot supported autoconfiguration with two DataSources, but I don't think it's going to happen soon:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/808

**UPDATE**

The author of the above article has published an updated approach:

https://scattercode.co.uk/2016/01/05/multiple-databases-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not with multiple instances of H2; but with DataSource injection.

I solved it by passing the Qualifier in method argument.

```
@Autowired
@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate") 
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("myDataSource") DataSource dataSource) { 
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); 
}
```